# Multiple TableViews in one View - Array of data sources?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to recreate a view controller similar to the "weather" app that comes stock on the iPhone. I've got a scrollview that contains an individual tableview per page, and I'm struggling to figure out a way to specify the data for each table view.

The tricky part is that the info in each tableview and the tableviews themselves change based on user defaults. Basically, I have an Array of dictionaries stored in user defaults, and each object in this array has its own tableview. Each dictionary contains a title, a lat and a long. When I create the tables, I also use the lat and long to get some data from the internet via an api call and parser. Here's the code:

```
    - (void)setupScrollView
{
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    //this is an array of dictionaries that hold a location title, as well as a lat and lng.
    NSArray *arrayForLocations = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[appDelegate.defaults objectForKey:@"arrayOfLocationDicts"]];
    NSLog(@"Array of Location Dicts holds: %@",arrayForLocations);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayForLocations.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
        UITableView *tbView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height - 40)];
        tbView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        tbView.tag = i;
        tbView.delegate = self;
        tbView.dataSource = self;
        [subview addSubview:tbView];

        UILabel *locationLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 260, 40)];
        locationLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        locationLabel.text = [[arrayForLocations objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"location_address"];
        [subview addSubview:locationLabel];

        pageControl.numberOfPages = [arrayForLocations count];
        //get coordinate from dictionary
        CLLocationCoordinate2D eventCoordinate;
        eventCoordinate.latitude = [[[arrayForLocations objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"location_latitude"]floatValue];
         eventCoordinate.longitude = [[[arrayForLocations objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"location_longitude"]floatValue];
        //turn coordinate into data
        SDJConnection *connection = [[SDJConnection alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *singleDataSource = [connection getEventInfoWithCoordinate:eventCoordinate];
        //store data in array
        [arrayOfDataSources addObject:singleDataSource];
        NSLog(@"array of Data Sources in the scrollsetup: %@",arrayOfDataSources);

    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * arrayForLocations.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

So now my problem is telling each of these tables what data to display. My first thought was to set the tag of the table, as I do above, and then have something like this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath -

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

         int i = tableView.tag;
        if (tableView.tag = i) {

            cell.textLabel.text = [[[arrayOfDataSources objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]eventTitle];
    }
```

that unfortunately hasn't been working for me correctly. Does anyone have any thoughts as to how to get this done?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For sure

```
if (tableView.tag = i) {
```

should be

```
if (tableView.tag == i) {
```

and even then, it's an odd construct -- not sure what you're trying to achieve there.  You set the i to the tag and then you check to see if the tag is i?  Doesn't really make sense -- that's where I'd suggest you take a close look and rethink your logic.

Comment: I basically have an array of data arrays, which each hold the info i want in a corresponding table. What i was trying to do was match up the table with the correct data array - in other words, table 0 gets data from the data array at index 0, table 1 gets data from the data array at index 1, and so forth. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I mean, what is the point of this particular conditional comparison?  What exactly is not working correctly, can you describe what is happening?